# combining arrayformula() with index() & match()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

I'd like to populate Table1 col-1-3 with data from Table2.

[image]

Instead of the value I get a #N/A saying: match didn't find the value "e1"

Here's the formula I'm using in c3

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A3:A);"";if(regexextract(B3:B;"^.")="e";index(F3:G5;match(F3:F5;0);2) ;B3:B)))
```

How can I fix this?

[Google table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z-cqbx0iaGeq28-rgyNfyGx4beswvFWjSuDd7N6uikk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In D3 I entered

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A3:A); IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3:B;F3:G; 2; 0); B3:B);))
```

See if that works for you?

Comment: Thanks for your solution which works well and I upvoted it. But, I'm not accepting it yet as a solution, because I was hoping to use Index/match. If that can't be solved, I'll accept yours.

Comment: IMO , vlookup is by far the best (and shortest!) solution for this issue.  The index-match simply won't work well in this scenario.

Comment: may I ask why you think, it wouldn't work

Comment: Let's assume you want to do an index-match when an 'e' is found in column B. The if-statement then will be 'true' and the index-match will fire. The issue will be that the match will try to match all cells in column B, not just the one cell with an 'e' in it.  Therefore it will return an error. If you take a look at the error you get in C5 you'll see what I mean.